# How to make a scrollable footer appear over a fixed content?

Tags: html, css

I have a website in which I have two buttons fixed in the bottom of my page like this:

[image]

And I have another div that is in the `<footer>` tag. So it looks like this:

```
<body>
   ...
   <div class="fixed-to-bottom">
       <input type="button" class="button1-in-bottom fixed-bottom" />
       <input type="button" class="button2-in-bottom fixed-bottom" />
   </div>

   <footer>
        <input type="button" class="button-in-footer" />
   </footer>
</body>
```

This is the css that makes `button1-in-bottom`and `button2-in-bottom` be fixed at bottom:

```
.fixed-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
   z-index: 2;
   left: 0;
}
```

When I scroll down (so I go to the bottom of the page) I want the bottom located in the footer be over the other two buttons like this:

[image]

But I don't find a way of how to do this. Can anybody help me find a solution to this problem? Thanks!

My snippet example:

```css
body {
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
}
.fixed-bottom-xs {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
}

.w-100 {
    width: 100%;
}

#select-passengers {
    margin-bottom: -1px!important;
}

.passengers-summary {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px 15px 13px 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.passengers-summary__label {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.passengers-summary__passengers {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.passengers-summary__passenger {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #4D4D4D;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.passengers-summary__passenger--adult:before {
    content: "\e916";
}
.passengers-summary__passenger:before {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #02A39C;
    margin-right: 3px;
    font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
}
.btn {
    background-color: #FFA745;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px 12px 15px;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif, "Verdana";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 19px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}
.btn--no-radius {
    border-radius: 0;
}
.btn--block {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer__container {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px)
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.footer {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="fixed-bottom-xs w-100 mobile-only" >
  <div class="w-100 mobile-only cta-bottom">
    <div class="passengers-summary" data-show="#passengers_layer" id="select-passengers">
      <div class="passengers-summary__content">
          <span class="passengers-summary__label">Passengers</span>
          <div class="passengers-summary__passengers">
            <div class="passengers-summary__passenger--adult passengers-summary__passenger">x1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn--block btn--no-radius">Continue</button>
</div> 

<footer class="footer__container">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer__links">
         <p class="footer__link" data-modal-open="modal-legal">Aviso legal, política de privacidad y cookies</p>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
</footer>
</body>
```

As you can see, the `footer` is behind the bottom buttons. But when I scroll down, I want the `button-in-footer` appear over the `button1-in-bottom`. Any idea on how I can achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried giving the `button1-in-bottom` and `button2-in-bottom` a `z-index` that is lower than `button-in-footer`?

Comment: can you add a working Snippet?

Comment: @AntonyMN But that would make my `button1-in-bottom` and `button2-in-bottom` be behind `button-in-footer` and I don't want that...

Comment: @Vishnuprasad sure sorry, I'm gonna prepare it.

Comment: I think scroll down Jquery function may help you.. http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/ayGwn/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set **bottom** value of `.fixed-bottom-xs` div equal to **height of footer** so that they are not overlapping each other

```css
body {
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
}
.fixed-bottom-xs {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 80px; /* set value equal to height of footer*/
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
}

.w-100 {
    width: 100%;
}

#select-passengers {
    margin-bottom: -1px!important;
}

.passengers-summary {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px 15px 13px 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.passengers-summary__label {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.passengers-summary__passengers {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.passengers-summary__passenger {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #4D4D4D;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.passengers-summary__passenger--adult:before {
    content: "\e916";
}
.passengers-summary__passenger:before {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #02A39C;
    margin-right: 3px;
    font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
}
.btn {
    background-color: #FFA745;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px 12px 15px;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif, "Verdana";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 19px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}
.btn--no-radius {
    border-radius: 0;
}
.btn--block {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer__container {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px)
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.footer {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="fixed-bottom-xs w-100 mobile-only" >
  <div class="w-100 mobile-only cta-bottom">
    <div class="passengers-summary" data-show="#passengers_layer" id="select-passengers">
      <div class="passengers-summary__content">
          <span class="passengers-summary__label">Passengers</span>
          <div class="passengers-summary__passengers">
            <div class="passengers-summary__passenger--adult passengers-summary__passenger">x1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn--block btn--no-radius">Continue</button>
</div> 

<footer class="footer__container">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer__links">
         <p class="footer__link" data-modal-open="modal-legal">Aviso legal, política de privacidad y cookies</p>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing! Thanksss

Answer (score 0):

You should give your footer a fixed position and z-index higher than the the div or the buttons,like below :

```css
.fixed-to-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
}
.button-in-footer
{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
z-index:3;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="fixed-to-bottom">
       <input type="button" class="button1-in-bottom fixed-bottom" value="button 1" />
       <input type="button" class="button1-in-bottom fixed-bottom" value="button 2" />
   </div>

   <footer>
        <input type="button" class="button-in-footer" value="your footer over" />
   </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: edite your code and past what do you have, and show me what do you want to do exactly!